# LNK1112 error when calling "make all" from Google OR-Tools

Tags: or-tools

I'm following the installation guide for google or-tools. When I tried to test the installation and following exactly the guide to "make all" in a x64 Native Tools Command Promt for VS2017, I still got the following error:

> cl /EHsc /MD /nologo /D_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -nologo /O2 -DNDEBUG -DUSE_CBC -DUSE_CLP /D__WIN32__ /Iinclude\src\windows /DGFLAGS_DLL_DECL= /DGFLAGS_DLL_DECLARE_FLAG= /DGFLAGS_DLL_DEFINE_FLAG= /Iinclude /I. -DUSE_GLOP -DUSE_BOP objs\costas_array.obj lib\ortools.lib psapi.lib ws2_32.lib /Febin\costas_array.exe
>   msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
>   make: *** [bin/costas_array.exe] Error 2

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Check or_tool_root/objs and remove any objects that might be created in your previous attempted calls with wrong setting.